Как сделать репозиторий публичным (!!!) через консоль?
Дело в том, что из за того что я потерял доступ к почтовому ящику, я не могу залогиниться на самом GitHub через браузер, где в принципе понятно было как и что делать, пользуюсь по сути только GitHub Desktop (настроена двухфакторная авторизация, код приходил прямо на ящик, доступ к которому потерян)
Так вот, есть ли какие то альтернативные способы "расприватить" репозиторий без захода на сайт GitHub?

скачай его и выложи в новом аккаунте

Лучше форкнуть - тогда в исходном репо будет ссылка на форк (есть кнопка на GitHub, доступна всем). Но судя по заголовку, это приватный репо. Так что если есть локальная версия (как минимум каталог .git) - опубликовать ее под новым аккаунтом (завести новый аккаунт, затем git remote add ..., git push ...). Если нет нигде кроме GitHub - только восстанавливать доступ.
